# Is there a good online tutorial for writing portable C?

Tags: c, solaris, portability, conditional-compilation

I have some tools I'm working on in portable C that works in Windows Visual Studio 2008 and gcc in Ubuntu Linux based on `#ifdef _WIN32` but adding support for Solaris seems to be trickier, especially if I want to support `cc` as well as `gcc`.

For one example I have some code which `sprintf`s into an allocated memory buffer which uses `vasprintf` on Linux/gcc and `_vscprintf`/`vsprintf` on Windows/MSVC. Neither are available on Solaris where I could use `vsnprintf` but I have no idea what to add to my `#ifdef`s or whether I should move to something else.

Hopefully I don't have to move to configure with cygwin, mingw.

Comment: There are lots of articles available....which have you looked at?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I did a few Google searches and StackOverflow searches and was surprised how little stuff was coming up for what seemed like an FAQ question so I decided to ask here where any answers will be easily found by Google for everybody from now on (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoconf(1)` manual has a [section on portable C programming](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Portable-C-and-C_002b_002b).

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do a test like this is to use something like gnu's autoconf + configure (or just plain configure). You can then test to see if vsprintf exists, failing that test for vasprintf, failing that test for vsnprintf, etc.. You can then get configure to define HAS_VSPRINTF and the like to use in your code, and write a wrapper function around the correct function.

This would be the most portable way to test,and the most portable way to then code up a solution, though perhaps also the most cumbersome - it'd definitely be what I'd do for production code though.

Comment: I used to have learning autoconf/configure on my todo list for a few years but every time I looked at it I could tell I would really need to put aside a big chunk of time, plus I thought it didn't work with Visual Studio which I do want to support.

Comment: It doesn't work with visual studio, but what you *can* do is use it to generate a config.h file (which it will do, you'll just have to do it under a fairly standard mingw box) and then ship that with your msvs projects.